# How do I remove and cap a difficult to access kitchen sprayer hose?

Tags: plumbing, water

I'm planning to remove my kitchen sink sprayer to make room for a water filter faucet. I'm stuck on how to remove and cap the existing sprayer outlet. The hose connection is inset beneath the counter in such a way that it seems difficult to fit a normal wrench into the hole (at least the wrenches I own). Do I need a special wrench for this? Or do I need to drill/cut the wood to better access? I'd rather not doing any cutting if I can avoid it. Or is there some other smarter solution? Thank you!
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: There are basin and other types of wrenches plumbers use for tight spaces.  With the water stain on the wood, I might think pulling the whole faucet up and check the sealing.

Comment: I've found that sprayer hose connections are often manufacturer/model specific, and you may have trouble finding a standard part to cap it with. That being said, it looks to me as though that was assembled before the faucet was fitted to the sink. You'll probably need to remove the 2 water inlet lines to lite it up off the sink to be able to easily disconnect the sprayer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to remove the faucet from the countertop to access that nut, and then you'll have to improvise a cap.

A smarter solution would be to drill a new hole for the dispenser on the opposite side.  That will be easier and you keep both functions.

If you are going to remove the faucet in order to disconnect the sprayer, IMO a better approach would be to then replace it with a new one that does not have a sprayer or that has a pull out sprayer at the end of the spout, requiring no extra hole.   My reasoning: It looks pretty old. You're upgrading. Once you make the effort to remove the old faucet it seems nuts to chop it up and put it back rather than put in a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've had some leakage there already...I'd consider just replacing the entire faucet.

Look at it this way: if you don't want a sprayer at all, you can buy a faucet without one and not have to deal with this.  If you like the spray function but simply want to add a filter, you can buy a faucet with a pullout sprayer.

Worst case, if you *have* to buy a faucet with a srayer you're not gonna use, it'll be a lot easier to cap it before installing.